# Silverstripe 3.4 - WYSIWYG editor not showing 2nd step for inserting link

Tags: tinymce, silverstripe

When inserting a link using the WYSIWYG content editor, the 2nd step does not show up. The first step with the radio buttons shows but when selecting an option nothing shows up on the 2nd step.

I tried removing a few unnecessary modules but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone encountered this before?

[image]

Comment: Can you see any javascript errors in the js-console?

Comment: No errors - all that shows is 
`jquery.js?m=1471873374:8240 XHR finished loading: GET "/admin/pages/edit/EditorToolbar/LinkForm/forTemplate".`

Comment: Hard to tell... Does it work in another browser, on another computer, in another network (e.g. at home vs in office) ...?

Comment: Tried Chrome, FF and IE, no luck. The client cannot see it on their computer on their network either. So definitely seems to be a conflict issue.

Comment: It works over here on CMS 3.4.1, german locale, FF. You could try it on a fresh install of CMS? Any errors when you try to choos another radio button (external url etc..)?

Comment: It will work on one instance of SS but not another. Same versions as well. So it must be something installed in just this instance but this is what I can't seem to work out. I have removed many modules but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: display-logic needed to be updated to the latest version.

https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic